# Connecting to WIFI network from Command Prompt

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, command-line, powershell

Is there a way to use the Windows 10 CMD MS-DOS Command Prompt to connect to a Wifi Network? The parameters for such a protocol could be simply as I have the network which I want to connect to and the password which can be let's say for example Network: **MyNetwork** Password: **StringInPrompt**. Is something like that feasible from the Command Prompt or would it need to be from the PowerShell? However, it's flat out not possible and I need to script something that would also be a valid answer? Yet, as well if I need to just click the WIFI logo in Windows 10 and connect to my wifi network. I tried to keep the question from not being too vague, or with broad answers because I narrowed out the possible ones. Please provide feedback if there are limitations to this idea.

Comment: Use NETS WLAN CONNECT to do this. Type NETSH WLAN CONNECT /?  to see how it works. As far I as I know this should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you already have been connected to that SSID with that computer can execute

`netsh wlan show profile`

identify your profile from the list and then execute

`netsh wlan connect ssid=wifi_ssid name=profile_from_the_list_that_is_used_to_connect_to_that_ssid`